# Pushing ViewController from string in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a class 'MyViewController.swift' and a string "MyViewController". How can I create an instance of that viewController from the string and push it in the navigation controller?

I've checked this answer ([How to create an object depending on a String in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25728282/how-to-create-an-object-depending-on-a-string-in-swift)) but it doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: May be this helps: http://www.spanware.com/blog/files/81bb0532b7f5c9ce9d015abc9b50c0e5-0.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift language NSClassFromString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030814/swift-language-nsclassfromstring)

Answer (score -2):

Assuming you are working with storyboard, you could extend `UIStoryboard` like:

```
class func mainStoryboard() -> UIStoryboard {
    return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
}

class func myViewController(s: String) -> UIViewController? {
    return mainStoryboard().instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(s) as? UIViewController
}
```

and then you can use it like

```
myVC = UIStoryboard.myViewController("controller")
myVC.view.frame = view.frame

view.addSubview(myVC.view)
addChildViewController(myVC)
myVC.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

or

```
let vc = getVC("controller")
vc!.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve
self.presentViewController(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Update:
If you are not using storyboards, you can add a something like this to your controller:

```
func getVC(s: String) -> UIViewController {
    switch s {
    case "myVc":
        return MyVC() as! UIViewController
    default:
        // handle default case
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not using storyboards, forgot to mention

Comment: Look can be work. I don't test, someone down vote but let a comment.